# How do I open this light fixture?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

Please tell me how to open it up to change the light bulb.

This is my friends room and I am a million miles away to help her.

She said, she try to twist the plastic rim but to no avail.

I think there is clip or the white dome can be twisted out.

Please provide some instructions on how to remove it.

[image]

[Click here to see original uncropped image](http://postimg.org/image/9o8ciqc8t/)

Comment: Hard to tell, but the dome of many small or lightweight fixtures are held up by spring clips. Pulling down (not too hard) on the dome ring might cause the dome to slide down about 4 inches allowing access to bulbs. If it resists a lot, stop.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How do I remove a flush mounted ceiling light fixture dome?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20740/how-do-i-remove-a-flush-mounted-ceiling-light-fixture-dome), [Am I missing some obvious way to change this lightbulb?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21088/am-i-missing-some-obvious-way-to-change-this-lightbulb), [How to change the bulb in an enclosed ceiling light?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11050/how-to-change-the-bulb-in-an-enclosed-ceiling-light)

Answer (score 1):

Really looks like mine.  Have someone to hold the metal surrounding in place while you turn the glass dome counter-clock wise for a quarter of a circle. The metal edge is in one piece and screwed to the electrical outlet.  I know this post has been online since 2 years, without any answers, although it has 406 views.  So I guess 406 persons do have that same fixture. I hope it help to next 406 persons...  and surely me in a couple of years when it will time to change the light bulb again and will have forget (again) how to do it...